404 error when accessing IBM Cloud Object Storage from Java
I currently am having trouble to access my Object Storage Bucket from a localhost Java springboot application. I am initializing the session, but when I reach the line
System.out.println(cos.getBucketFaspConnectionInfo(BUCKET_NAME).toString());
It ends up throwing the following error:
com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Not Found (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found; Request ID: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null
I don't know how to read the exception and I don't know what could be failing. Already tried between an IAM API key ID and the Service Credential API Key ID and it didn't make a difference in the error output. I don't even know what exactly the 404 error not found is referencing, if it means the bucket or something else.
My code is the following:

    private static String COS_ENDPOINT = <Endpoint provided by Object Storage's Service Credentials>;
    private static String COS_API_KEY_ID = "<API provided by Object Storage's Service Credentials>;
    private static String COS_AUTH_ENDPOINT = "https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token";
    private static String COS_SERVICE_CRN = <Bucket Instance's CRN>;
    private static String COS_BUCKET_LOCATION = "us-south";
    private static String BUCKET_NAME = <Bucket Instance's name>;

@Override
    public S3ObjectStreamDto fetchPicture(String name) {
        String nameOfFile = fetchByName(name).getPictureName();
        System.out.println(nameOfFile);
        S3ObjectInputStream streamToReturn = null;
        try
        {
            AmazonS3 cos = initializeOneTimeUseCOS();
            System.out.println(cos.getBucketFaspConnectionInfo(BUCKET_NAME).toString());
            System.out.println(cos.toString());
            streamToReturn = cos.getObject(BUCKET_NAME, nameOfFile).getObjectContent();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(streamToReturn == null)
        {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Fetch picture", name, nameOfFile);
        }
        
        return new S3ObjectStreamDto(streamToReturn);
    }

    private AmazonS3 initializeOneTimeUseCOS() throws Exception
    {
        AmazonS3 cosClient;
        SDKGlobalConfiguration.IAM_ENDPOINT = COS_AUTH_ENDPOINT;
        try
        {
            cosClient = createClient(COS_API_KEY_ID, COS_SERVICE_CRN, COS_ENDPOINT, COS_BUCKET_LOCATION);
            return cosClient;
        } catch(SdkClientException sdke)
        {
            System.out.println(sdke.getMessage());
            throw new InternalServerErrorException("Fetch picture", "Failure when initializing COS client." + sdke.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private static AmazonS3 createClient(String api_key, String service_instance_id, String endpoint_url, String location)
    {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicIBMOAuthCredentials(api_key, service_instance_id);
        ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration().withRequestTimeout(5000);
        clientConfig.setUseTcpKeepAlive(true);

        AmazonS3 cos = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration(endpoint_url, location)).withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
                .withClientConfiguration(clientConfig).build();

        return cos;
    }

The line of code:
fetchByName(name).getPictureName()'s implementation is not depicted here but it is working as expected.
I tried changing the API ID Keys and it didn't work. I tried changing the regions and it also didn't work.
I am expecting to be able to access basic information from the bucket.
